# Convert a rating to a probabilty where lower is better

Tags: probability

I have a loose rating system that I can convert into a probability:

A standard rating where higher is better:

```
            Rating       Probability
Team A       50             50/(50+15+10)= 66.7%
Team B       15             20%
Team C       10             13.3%
```

But what if the ratings are lower the better. To calculate probability would it just be the inverse? And how would i calculate it if a rating was zero?

For example where lower the rating the better the team:

```
            Rating       Probability
Team A       0              ?
Team B       30             ?
Team C       50             ?
```

In this instance, Team A is the highest rating team.

Any ideas on the best way to approach this? thanks!

Comment: Is $0$ the minimum possible rating and $50$ the maximum possible rating?

Comment: 0 would be the minumum yes but the maximum could be up to 200 or so. 90% of rating would be 50 or under

Comment: One option is just take the inverses and divide by the new total amount. As you point out, you can't do this with a rating of zero so the natural solution would be "Change to zero every rating different from zero and divide the probability equally among the zero rating teams" (in your example would be (100%, 0%, 0%)). But this is only a possible solution, whether this fits your problem is not clear, because you don't state what's the purpose of this.

Comment: @SOK Suppose $200$ is the maximum rating. Given "reverse rating" $0, 30, 50$, we can transform them into "standard rating" by computing $200 - 0, 200 - 30, 200 - 50$. Then you can compute the probability using the usual method. Of course, you need to check if this method makes sense at all for your applications.

Comment: thanks! its basically a machine learning rating for a team in a timed race. It has been modelled to predict `minutes` finished behind the leader. When the predictions are finished, I set the lowest rated time to zero and all other teams behind that. Or would it be a better way to leave the orginial numbers as is, an example being `Team A` a rating of 5, `Team B` 35 and `Team C` 55 and use an inverse of some kind instead of scaling `Team A` to 0